# Простые числа в двумерном массиве?

Tags: c++

Дан двумерный массив. Возвести в квадрат все простые числа. Я написал так, но это не работает. Помогите !

```
for (int i = 1; i <= row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= col; j++)
        {
            if (a[i - 1][j - 1] % i*j == 0)
            {
                a[i-1][j-1] *= a[i-1][j-1];
            }
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            cout<<a[i][j]<<" " ;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Так а что имеется ввиду под этой проверкой `a[i - 1][j - 1] % i*j == 0`? Что она проверяет?

Answer (score 1):

```
bool isPrime(int n)
{
    n = abs(n);  // На всякий случай, если рассматриваются не только натуральные числа...

    if (n < 2 || n%2 == 0) return false;
    for(int i = 3; i*i <= n; i += 2)
        if (n%i == 0) return false;
    return true;
}

....
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        if (isPrime(a[i][j]))  a[i][j] *= a[i][j];
```

Comment: У вас функция имеет две точки выхода. Это нарушает заветы Дейкстры и ведет к плохо отлаживаемому коду.

Comment: @becouse Вы всерьез? или просто решили приколоться, но не знаете, как? :)

Comment: Серьезно. Функция с несколькими точками выхода это потенциальная проблема, грязный код.

Comment: @becouse Ничего, бывает. Со временем попустит, не переживайте...

Comment: у вас нет рациональных доводов в пользу наличия в данном случае у функции нескольких точек выхода.

Answer (score 0):

Объявляем функцию

```
bool isPrime(int n) {
   int i=2, flag = 1;
   while (i<=n/2 && flag==1){
      if(n%i==0) {
         flag=0;
      }
      else {
       i++;
   }
   }
  return flag;
}
```

Далее используем для вашего массива

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if (isPrime(a[i][j]) == 1)
            {
                a[i][j] = a[i][j]*a[i][j];
            }
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            cout<<a[i][j]<<" " ;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Неэффективно...

Comment: @Harry да у вас тоже) где решето или вероятностный тест?)

Comment: так это школьная задача. Хватит и половины от числа. Кроме того решето нельзя использовать на неупорядоченном массиве.

Comment: @pavel В принципе, можно строить решето по ходу дела, но будет ли это эффективнее на небольших числах? А по поводу вероятностного теста - ну а как попадется то самое число? :) Да и на небольших значениях (помещающихся в int) вероятностный тест проигрывает...

Comment: @Harry до 10^18 вероятностный тест работает 100% (проверено) по скорости он быстрее чем перебор до корня) и сильно быстрее.

Comment: @pavel вероятностный тест на то и вероятностный, что распознает составное число с вероятностью 1/2^n. Собственно для чисел меньше 1000000 поиск до корня и до половины дают одинаковую оценку сложности, так как с очень большой вероятностью составное число имеет маленький делитель.

Так что вероятностный тест нужен там где он нужен на числах размером более 50 знаков.

Comment: @pavel Мы говорим об одном и том же - Миллере-Рабине? А какого количества раундов достаточно для этого диапазона?

Comment: @Harry BPSW. я о нём думал)

Comment: @pavel Писать долго... А так было бы интересно сравнить по скорости.

Comment: @Harry http://e-maxx.ru/algo/bpsw тут исходники есть)

Answer (score -2):

Неверная проверка на простое число.
Корректная проверка на простоту:

```
for (int l = 1; l <= sqrt(num); l++)
 if (num % l == 0) num *= num;
```

Comment: кхм... вы сами пробовали запустить ваш ответ? Кстати может быть даже бесконечный цикл)

Comment: эээ…. что-то я в затруднении, что тут имелось в виду?